# Geometry nodes : Is there a way to assign a material to a specific instance?

Tags: materials, shaders, geometry-nodes, procedural, instances

Currently building a geometry nodes setup that create a web of sphere distributed along the point of a curve as follows:

I would like to have the spheres with **more than 1 connection to be green** and the spheres with **1 or less to be yellow**. Is there a way to assign materials that way ? or atleast control the seed generated by the **Object Info > Random factor** ? (Blend file uploaded)

[image]

[image]

Node setup for the distribution :

[image]

Shader nodes :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something ... **Vertex Neighbors** ... cubes are green. If an instance is at point with less than 2 connections material is pink.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Another question : I've noticed doubled control points on the curve I used, mainly due because of multiple segments joined at a single point. Is there way to use only 1 curve handle for 3+ segment intersect ? The resulting issue is doubled instances

Comment: Why don't use a Mesh instead of Curve object directly? Or you can add Convert to Mesh node and Merge by distance node just for the purpose of Capture Attribute ...

Comment: I need to have spheres moving along the curve by using the factor of the Sample curve node, kind of a stream of instances going from one sphere to another. It is apparently not doable when I have multiple splines in 1 curve object.